# Jquery mobile UI not showing up properly with asp.net

Tags: jquery, user-interface, mobile

[image: Sample Image]

The last element of nav bar is displaying like that.. I tried a couple of different techniques but can't get it right. Please have  a look. This is my code of a user defined control in asp.net

<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Check.ascx.cs" Inherits="Project.Check" %>

- Home
- Assign Work Orders
- Fill Form
- Add New Home
- Edit Home

Answer (score 0):

Please see the actual code

- Home
- Assign Work Orders
- Fill Form
- Add New Home
- Edit Home

--%>